# Creating an alarm app

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler

I want to create an alarm which will stream an audio file from the server. So basically I want to start a foreground service or an activity at a specific time accurately. Should I use the jobscheduler or the alarmmanager? I have read that the jobscheduler cannot start a job accurately at a specific time. Will background restrictions for Oreo prevent alarmmanager from firing in doze mode. Should I use jobscheduler to start a foreground service before the specific time(so it doesn't have to be accurate), then start the alarm from the foreground service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AlarmManager` with any of `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`, `setAlarmClock()` or `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` methods.

**Based on the documentation**

> - Standard AlarmManager alarms (i ncluding setExact() and setWindow()) are deferred to the next maintenance window.
>
>   - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
>   - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.